# Ubuntu 20.04 and ldap authentification

Tags: ssh, ldap

I struggle a little bit with setting up ldap authentification on Ubuntu 20.04. I followed [this guide](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-authenticate-a-linux-client-with-ldap-server/), that is, I installed the packages `libnss-ldap libpam-ldap ldap-utils nscd`.

`nsswitch.conf` looks

```
passwd:         files systemd ldap
group:          files systemd ldap
shadow:         files ldap
gshadow:        files
```

I changed the line in `/etc/pam.d/common-password` so that it reads

```
password [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die] pam_ldap.so try_first_pass
```

And I added the following line to `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session optional            pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=022
```

Now I'm not sure about whether it is necessary that the user exists locally or not. If the user exists, everything works fine. If not, I get the following messages in auth.log:

```
Jan 27 07:06:55 myserver sshd[4479]: Invalid user myuser from xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxx::xx port 50556
Jan 27 07:07:03 myserver sshd[4479]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan 27 07:07:03 myserver sshd[4479]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxx::xx 
Jan 27 07:07:03 myserver sshd[4479]: pam_ldap: error trying to bind as user "CN=myuser,OU=Users,OU=TEST,DC=ad,DC=test,DC=example,DC=de" (Invalid credentials)
Jan 27 07:07:05 myserver sshd[4479]: Failed password for invalid user myuser from xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxx::xx port 50556 ssh2
```

Am I doing something wrong, and the user should be automatically created (if not existing locally) or is it working as expected, and I have to create the users beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the fully qualified domain name when you login? Logging in using AD users (LDAP) we must use the full name as such

ssh myUser@COMPANY.PVT@THESERVERHOSTNAME